# How to access the value of cell outside of method in collectionView in Swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm using JSQMessage library with the `JSQMessageCollectionViewCell`. How can i access the value of cell outside of method `cellForItem atIndexPath`.

Here is the method

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

    if Array_Messages[indexPath.item].senderId == senderId {
        cell.textView?.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.cellBottomLabel.textInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 35)
        let second = ClassMessages[indexPath.row].Time.doubleValue
        let time = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: second)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

        cell.cellBottomLabel.text = "\(String(describing: newMess.Status!)) \(dateFormatter.string(from: time))"  
    } 
    return cell
}
```

I try to do this but got the error

```
@IBAction func btTrash(_ sender: Any) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
    print("aaa \(cell?.cellBottomLabel.text)")
}
```

Error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional`

How can i fix this? Thank for your helping !

Comment: Ideally it should work. Can you check whether first cell `IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 0)` is created in `cellForRowAt` before pressing `btTrash`.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but i dont know what you means? Can you please make it clearly ?

Comment: Can you put print inside `override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { ` and check whether cell is created for  indexPath of row 0 and section 0.

Comment: a i know, may be the problem is here. Thank you for your replying

Comment: Should the first line in the method not be to dequeue and cast a reusable cell?

Comment: @Chris: yes i know the problem is. Thank for your comment

Comment: I believe the problem occur due to not properly deque the cell. Can you provide me the full implementation of super class so that i will provide you an explaination in good implementation.

Comment: Yes bro, thank for your helping. I'm now building the Chat App. The super class is very long code. If you happy, i will send it via your email. Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to add this checkBox in storyBoard and make it hidden by setting true to its isHidden property, and on your controller take one global Bool set as false. so when your bar button is cliked make this variable true and reload the table.

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath check It like this.

```
var shouldShowCheckBox = false

func barButtonTaped(){
shouldShowCheckBox = !(shouldShowCheckBox)
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      btnCheckBox.isHidden = shouldShowCheckBox        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 4, Swift 5

You can use `cellForItem` to access your cell outside of the collectionView delegate. In this case, the `MerchantCell` located in row 4.

```
if let merchantCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: 4, section: 0)) as? MerchantCell {
    merchantCell.refreshMerchant()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access something like that also.

```
class RegistrationVc: UIViewController {

    var objCell = RegistrationCell()

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RegistrationCell", for: indexPath) as! RegistrationCell
        objCell = cell
        return cell
    }
    @IBAction func btnContinue(_ sender: UIButton) {

            objCell.txtUserName.errorMessage = "please enter user name"
     }
```